# .NET CORE 3 The base path of a Windows Service is returning C:\Windows\System32, But actual folder is D:\MyCustomService

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

Here AppContext.BaseDirectory always returning C:\Windows\System32 but we are expecting  D:\MyCustomService - where we have the actual files.

Please find my following code. Can you please suggest where it's going wrong and also I have tried all other options like CurrentDirectory, System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location,  Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName; etc

We have installed the server by using following command

sc create "myServiceName" binPath="D:\MyCustomService\myServiceName.exe"

```
public class Program
{
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string loggerTemplate = @"{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [{Level:u4}]<{ThreadId}> [{SourceContext:l}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}";

            var baseDir = AppContext.BaseDirectory;

            Console.WriteLine(baseDir);

            var logfile = Path.Combine(baseDir, "App_Data", "logs", "log.txt");
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .Enrich.With(new ThreadIdEnricher())
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.Console(LogEventLevel.Information, loggerTemplate, theme: AnsiConsoleTheme.Literate)
                .WriteTo.File(logfile, LogEventLevel.Information, loggerTemplate, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, retainedFileCountLimit: 90)
                .CreateLogger();
            try
            {
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal(ex, "Application terminated unexpectedly");
            }
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            })
            .UseWindowsService();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you can not because a Windows service runs in the folder you mention, read [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#current-directory-and-content-root):

> Don't attempt to use GetCurrentDirectory to obtain a resource path
>   because a Windows Service app returns the C:\WINDOWS\system32 folder
>   as its current directory.

Answer (score 1):

use IHostEnviroment, in Development or Staging you can use Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), but in production you have to use _environment.ContentRootPath because default path for windows services is "C:\Windows\system32"